# How to mirror a hard disk and restore it later without OS installed?

Tags: windows, backup, restore, mirroring

My windoes 7 has been installed on a 128gb SSD drive `C:`. Unfortunately I screwed some programs that now I require to reinstall windows again.

But before formatting my OS drive I want to make a mirror that in case of regretion! I would be able to restore it to pervious state.

What I am looking for is a free or probably very cheap soloution to doing so, without the need for any os being installed (or maximum it can work on a live CD or something, as long as it can restore the mirror in windows FS)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows backup by Imaging](http://superuser.com/questions/7739/windows-backup-by-imaging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/). We use it in our company, and in my opinion it is the best tool to copy / clone / restore disks and partitions. It is independent from the OS (it can be started in a live USB) and it allows to use network devices (in our case NFS shares) as your depot of disk images.

I recommend it.

Comment: I *also* recommend Clonezilla for a free one

Comment: You guys know we don't like duplicate questions, right? :)